# Given an npm package, how do I know whether it will work in browser?

Tags: npm

I've recently installed some npm package (recommended Kubernetes client) for my react app.
After writing code that uses the package and deploying the code for testing I got some weird errors about missing functions or packages. Then I've read the documentation and realized that the package was Node-only.

Is there any way to check that the npm package works in browser before writing code that uses the package?

Python packages specify compatible python versions. Do npm packages have something like this whether they indicate support for particular Node versions and the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Some packages/libraries contain `.browserlistrc` file which I've found to be a starting point to find out the browsers and platforms the devs intend to support or have their code compile for. While it may not always be true and the package might just be able to support a browser that isn't mentioned, it's a good starting point. It surely helps to find out if IE (the bane of front-end dev) is supported or not.

Then again many packages don't necessarily include a `.browserlistrc`. You can then check the `package.json` for a `"browserslist"` field.

If neither are found, you can always clone the repo and add your own `.browserlistrc` in the root with queries that will let you know if the package supports your intended browser or platform - little more work but yeah it can help. Not full proof but a decent enough way to find out.

**Though the best answer is really to just ask the maintainers.**